# eclipse export Revision graph in picture

Tags: eclipse, image, revision-graph

I have a big repository to browse, I use revision graph in eclipse.

I want to save revision graph in picture for local use ? 
I look to export option but no one !!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`Windows + PrintScreen`, then paste it to `mspaint` with `Ctrl+V`? Or any screen capture tools like [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/download/jing/)?

Comment: What if the image is larger than the view port? Changing screen resolution? What about the screenshot having poor resolution then?